# 01427. 00000 - "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm getting 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error while executing below procedure. the issue , what i believe , is in subquery

`SELECT paymentterm FROM temp_pay_term WHERE pid   = d.xProject_id`

but how can i get rid of it.Now, i have added the complete code. please check and let me know the wrong tell me if more info. is to be provided.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE paytermupdate IS
  recordcount    INT;
  vardid         NUMBER(38);
  varpaymentterm VARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
  BEGIN
    recordcount := 0;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO recordcount
    FROM temp_pay_term;

    IF recordcount > 0 THEN
      FOR x IN (SELECT DISTINCT r.ddocname
                FROM temp_pay_term p, docmeta d, revisions r
                WHERE TO_CHAR(p.pid) = d.xproject_id AND r.did = d.did             )
      LOOP
        SELECT MAX(did) INTO vardid
        FROM revisions r
        WHERE r.ddocname = x.ddocname
        GROUP BY r.ddocname;

        UPDATE docmeta d
        SET paymentterm = (
          SELECT paymentterm
          FROM temp_pay_term
          WHERE pid = d.xproject_id
        )
        WHERE d.did = vardid;

        INSERT INTO documenthistory (dactionmillis, dactiondate, did, drevclassid,
                                     duser, ddocname, daction, dsecuritygroup, paymentterm)
          SELECT
            to_number(TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'FF')) AS dactionmillis,
            TRUNC(systimestamp, 'dd')              AS dactiondate,
            did,
            drevclassid,
            'sysadmin'                             AS duser,
            ddocname,
            'Update'                               AS daction,
            dsecuritygroup,
            paymentterm
          FROM revisions
          WHERE did = vardid;

      END LOOP;

      COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END paytermupdate;
```

Comment: This error is returned when a subquery (a SELECT inside a query) returns more than one row when only one row is expected. Your incomplete code is not enough for us to really help here unfortunately.

Comment: If the error is in the line: "SELECT paymentterm FROM temp_pay_term WHERE pid = d.xProject_id", you should post the complete statement (that ends at " WHERE d.did = vardid;") to help anyone help you.

Comment: added the complete code in query. please check. Thanks

Comment: UPDATE docmeta d
  SET paymentterm =
    (SELECT paymentterm
    FROM temp_pay_term
    WHERE pid   = d.xProject_id

    )
  WHERE d.did = vardid; Seems temp_pay_term table has more than one  record for particular xProject_id. You should add additional condition to make this subquery returning no more than 1 row for particular value.

Comment: yes. above quer is giving multiple records but when i add a simple condition as below, it do not give results." select paymentterm from temp_pay_term where pid = d.xProject_id and rownum <= 1 order by paytermtimestamp desc"

Answer (score 0):

Do you use something like

select x,y,z, (subquery) from  ?

If you are getting ORA-01427 you should think how to make filter conditions in your subquery  more restrictive, and these restrictions should be business reasonable, not just simply "and rownum <=1".

Answer (score 0):

As you want to update a record through that sub query you should put more filter conditions in it. You can decide on the filter conditions on the basis of the value you want to update in the table in outer query. If there are more values which satisfy the condition (which I do not believe is ideal but just in case) then rownum <=1 would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Two basic options come to mind. I'll start with the simplest.

First, add distinct to the subquery.

```
SET paymentterm =
    (SELECT distinct paymentterm
    FROM temp_pay_term
    WHERE pid   = d.xProject_id
)
```

Second, if you're receiving multiple distinct values from the subquery, then you will either have to *(a)* rework your script to not use a subquery or *(b)* limit values returned (as @Baljeet suggested) using more filter criteria or *(c)* pick which of the multiple distinct values you want using an aggregate function.

Using the aggregate method, I'm guessing PaymentTerm is a number of months or years? Even if it's a n/varchar field (i.e., "6 months"), you can still use the MIN() and MAX() aggregates (or at least you can in t-sql). If it's a numeric field, you could also use average. You'll have to figure out which works best for your business needs.